# How can I patch / mock logging.getlogger()

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I have this code that I want to test:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        log.debug('Init')
```

but I cannot figure out how to assert that log.debug was called with 'Init'

I tried patching logger but inspecting it I only found a getLogger mock.

I'm sure its simple, but I just cant figure it!

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: What mocking library do you use?

Comment: I'm on Python 3.3, so unittest.mock

Comment: Facing something similar.. help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264007/how-to-mock-logging-filehandler-in-python

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use `patch.object()` on the actual logging object. that lets you verify that you're using the correct logger too:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('path.to.module.under.test')
with mock.patch.object(logger, 'debug') as mock_debug:
    run_code_under_test()
    mock_debug.assert_called_once_with('Init')
```

Alternatively, if you're using Pytest, then it already has a fixture that captures logs for you:

```py
def test_bar(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
        run_code_under_test()
    assert "Init" in caplog.text
    # or, if you really need to check the log-level
    assert caplog.records[-1].message == "Init"
    assert caplog.records[-1].levelname == "DEBUG"
```

More info in the [pytest docs on logging](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/logging.html)

Comment: This actually works with @patch format as well. Just prefix your function with `@mock.patch.object(logging.getLogger('path.to.module.under.test'), 'debug')` and give the function the extra argument `mock_debug`.

Answer (score 40):

Assuming `log` is a global variable in a module `mymod`, you want to mock the actual instance that `getLogger` returned, which is what invokes `debug`. Then, you can check if `log.debug` was called with the correct argument.

```
with mock.patch('mymod.log') as log_mock:
    # test code
    log_mock.debug.assert_called_with('Init')
```

Comment: Can't believe it was so simple, just what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick reply too!

Comment: From 3.4 on, the test framework includes a self.assertLogs() method! Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920727/2498426

Comment: Just to add, `mymod` can be the path to your python file, replace the / in the filepath with period like so: `myappname/cool_feature/foo.py` -> `mock.patch('myappname.cool_feature.foo.log')`

Answer (score 5):

I am late for this question but another of way to achieve it is:

```
@patch('package_name.module_name.log')
def test_log_in_A(self, mocked_log):

    a = A()
    mocked_log.debug.assert_called_once_with('Init')
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class Test(TestCase):
    def test_logger(self):
        with patch('logging.Logger.warning') as mocked_logger:
            call_func()
            mocked_logger.assert_called_once_with('log')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example

```py
"""
Source to test
"""
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("abc")

def my_fonction():
    logger.warning("Oops")

"""
Testing part
"""
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

abc_logger = logging.getLogger("abc")

class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(abc_logger, "warning", MagicMock())
    def test_my_fonction(self):
        # When
        my_fonction()
        # Then
        abc_logger.warning.assert_called_once()
```