# Python Log Capture During Unit Tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging

I am trying to capture logs that are created during the course of my python unittests and saw the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049375/576333.

However, I cannot get this code to work and will freely admit that my understanding of python's logging module is not fantastic.

Essentially, I am adding the mock handler in that post like so:
    my_logger.addHandler(MockLoggingHandler)

and when the code calls, say, `my_logger.info(some_message)` I get
    AttributeError: class MockLoggingHandler has no attribute 'level'

I am not sure where to start on figuring out what is missing from the `MockLoggingHandler` class. BTW, I am using Python 2.6.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an *instance* of the class, like so:

```
my_logger.addHandler(MockLoggingHandler())
```

Note the `()` after `MockLoggingHandler`.